# Regex extract contents

Tags: javascript, html, json, regex

So, I have the following data here:

```
{"screenName":"fubars","msgHash":"C5STUYqhjzNiP6LLVbPlTF3zYLVYXHrm","imgURL":null,"userColor":"#00a4a0","messageTime":"2:50 PM","messageDate":1442256635621,"accountType":"m","accountTypeID":"z2ZkdXqck-JO45hqXVXH","isModerator":"","badges":""
```

I've written some regex to extract strings, but if I search for example "screenName" it gets the "fubars" part and the rest of the string, I only want the "fubars" part...
code:

```
  function extractSummary(iCalContent, what) {
  eval("var rxm = /\""+what+"\": \"(.*)\"/g");
  console.log(rxm);
  setTimeout(function(){},1500);
  var arr = rxm.exec(iCalContent);
  return arr[1]; 
}
```

Comment: just... why... `JSON.parse`

Comment: What format is the data you have in?  Do you have a JSON string?  Do you have a JavaScript object?  Do you know how to access properties of an object?

Comment: P.S. `obj.screenName`

Comment: @ssdev: Could you please provide a working snippet to see what you actually have? Are you looking for [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lhuf1vq/)?

Comment: What is that `eval()` line?!  What is that doing?  Get rid of that!

Answer (score 0):

If you have some data in the form of a JSON string, you can use `JSON.parse` to convert it into a JSON object. You can then use `dot` or `index` property getters.

```
var jsonString = '{"screenName":"fubars","msgHash":"C5STUYqhjzNiP6LLVbPlTF3zYLVYXHrm"}';
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

console.log(jsonObject.screenName);
console.log(jsonObject['screenName']);
```

There's no need to use regexes here.